# Legacy code - looking for a function which emulates qbasic decimal to text

Tags: porting, qbasic

I could sit down a write this, but in the interests of not reinventing the wheel, I wanted to check that someone hasn't already done this.

I have to migrate over a little legacy tool which generates a text file containing a table of numeric values generated by a small tool. It was written many years back in DOS QBasic.

The only problem with the task is that QBasic had quite a few pecularities in decimal to text conversion. Lots of small exceptions.

The resultant file is imported into an old machine which works perfectly with the QBasic generated file, but when I pass it 6 or 7 digit precision decimals the results are not correct. QBasic output when writing decimals varies from 7 down to 3 digits of decimal depending on the whole number part and also generates decimals in the 0.0000E+1 format if there is no whole number part and there are zeros after the decimal point.

Has anyone seen a collection of functions which behave the same way as qbasic? Language doesn't matter. Googling hasn't turned up anything so far.

Comment: It sounds very similar to [`printf("%G", x);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: You can control the output of QBasic using `PRINT #f, USING "#.######"; value` instead of `PRINT #f, value`. Otherwise, have a look at C's `fscanf` function with the `%lf` specifier and a variable of type `double` (unless the values have type `SINGLE`, in which case you should use `%f` and a variable of type `float`). Being floating-point, you'll undoubtedly lose precision unless you can regenerate the file using another format with an acceptable amount of precision as I mentioned already. Beware output like `0.0000D+1` in which the `D` must be changed `E` to work with `fscanf`.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a function which does the same as the old Qbasic one, without having to go through each possibility and writing it myself. The problem I have is that what I'm writing out is correct, mathematically, but upon importing, the result is different. So, I would guess it has something to do with where I'm importing it into, which was probably set up to expect QBasic style formatting and some of the decimals are not being correctly handled.

Comment: Why do you need to migrate the tool? If it's only so you can run it on a modern OS, then a couple options can be to run it via DosBox, or compile it in QB64 so you can run in on Windows/Mac/Linux.

Comment: Thats what we've been doing, but its kinda crazy to have to fire up dosbox and then open, qbasic and then run a basic file, just to generate a little text file of values. The program is tiny and the only issue I have with the logic is the writing of decimals to a text file.

Comment: Try compiling it in QB64 (qb64.net). That's a modern version of Qbasic that compiles for modern OSes and should be compatible with old Qbasic code. You can save it as an EXE so you don't have to launch Qbasic each time you need to run it.

Comment: If QB64 isn't up your alley, can you post a sample of 10-15 generated numbers that are quite distinct from each other, for reference? That'd help me know exactly what to replicate with a function or regex in something like C, PHP, Python, Ruby, etc.

Comment: In the end I just went through a load of values and wrote a little routine which generates the numbers in the same format. There weren't as many combinations as I thought at first. Thanks for the suggestions in any case.